# Нет связи с сервером через прокси

Tags: proxy

Есть игровой сервер garry`s mod, стоит на хостинге. В виду блокировки провайдером приходится играть через прокси. Прокси организовал на вдс в Голландии с помощью 3proxy. Вдруг пропала связь с игровым сервером. Если пинговать с голландского компа - все ок, подключаюсь к нему через прокси и пингую игровой сервер - тишина. Куда копать? В сапорте сообщили, что мои проблемы их не интересуют.